# No plugin descriptor found at META-INF/maven/plugin.xml in jooq 3.11.11 trial version

Tags: java, sql-server, maven-plugin, jooq

I am trying to generate java class from mssql database using jooq. Currently, I'm using trial version to check the feasibility of code generation and am getting the below error. Pls help.

> [ERROR] Failed to parse plugin descriptor for
>   org.jooq.trial:jooq-codegen-maven:3.11.11
>   (C:\Users\developer.m2\repository\org\jooq\trial\jooq-codegen-maven\3.11.11\jooq-codegen-maven-3.11.11.jar):
>   No plugin descriptor found at META-INF/maven/plugin.xml -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginDescriptorParsingException: Failed to
>   parse plugin descriptor for org.jooq.trial:jooq-codegen-maven:3.11.11
>   (C:\Users\developer.m2\repository\org\jooq\trial\jooq-codegen-maven\3.11.11\jooq-codegen-maven-3.11.11.jar):
>   No plugin descriptor found at META-INF/maven/plugin.xml   at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.extractPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:186)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:286)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:244)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:130)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:144)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)    at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:290)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:194)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: No plugin descriptor found at
>   META-INF/maven/plugin.xml     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.extractPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:236)
>     ... 26 more

Pom.xml:

```
<plugin>                    
    <groupId>org.jooq.trial</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
    <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>jooq-codegen</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${skip.jooq.generation}</skip>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    <configuration>
        <jdbc>                           
         <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>
         <url>${database.url}</url>
         <user></user>
         <password></password>
        </jdbc>
        <generator>
            <name>org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator</name>
            <database>                               
                <name>org.jooq.meta.sqlserver.SQLServerDatabase</name>
                <includes>.*</includes>
                <excludes></excludes>
                <inputSchema>dbo</inputSchema>
            </database>
            <target>                                 
                <packageName>org.blackdread.sqltojava.jooq</packageName>
                <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
            </target>
        </generator>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: What's the full error that you're getting when you pass `-e` to Maven?

Comment: Added the error @Lukas Eder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While installing maven into my local repo, it missed out the plugin.xml inside jar. Not sure how though.But I replaced the jar with the actual one and it works. Now I have to check how to install the jar in maven with plugin.xml